# Tomcat Version Upgrade for ZK Web application

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, zk

**I am developing a ZK Web application, it uses java 1.7, ZK version 6.5.2 and Apache Tomcat 6 (The default tomcat version described in ZK documentation).
Now i have a requirement to upgrade the Apache Tomcat to the higher compactable version with (ZK 6.5.2 and Java 1.7). Which is the higher version avilable? How i can done a upgradation? Any pointers will helpfull.
When i looked into lib  folder i seen the following jar files tomcat-dbcp.jar, 
tomcat-juli.jar, tomcat-coyote.jar**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should just download the new Tomcat (http://tomcat.apache.org/) from here and extract it to  old current path and if you're using eclipse for development some older versions of eclipse don't support recent versions of tomcat this means you should update your eclipse too.

https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Quick_Start/Create_and_Run_Your_First_ZK_Application_with_Eclipse_and_ZK_Studio follow this guide maybe this can be helpful.